# Facelet Tag with optional id attribute

Tags: jsf, attributes, tags, facelets

I've been trying to build a Facelet tag (labeled input). It worked fine to the point where I try to turn the id into a conditional attribute. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using (PrimeFaces) and the thing I'm trying to do is something like:

```
<h:inputText>
    <c:if test="#{id ne null}">
        <f:attribute name="id" value="#{id}" />
    </c:if>
</h:inputText>
```

And this how I expect to use it:

```
<my:outputPanel />
```

or

```
<my:outputPanel id="foo" />
```

When I try o use it I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.setValueExpression(UIComponent.java:484)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AttributeHandler.apply(AttributeHandler.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:96)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
```

This works fine with attributes other than id. It seems to be a kind of restriction concerning the id attribute. Thank you in advance for any directions.

Comment: Does it work when using a plain jsf component (none-pf one) like an `h:panelGrid`?

Comment: @Kukeltje, it doesn't work with plain components either. I tried it with a h:inputText.

Comment: So it is not PrimeFaces related... Did you try MyFaces instead of Mojarra?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try as soon as possible MyFaces aproach. For now I have to finish this project and I'm going to write 2 codes in my facelet (one with the presence of the id and other without it) so I can choose each of them with the jstl c:choose-c:when-c:otherwise. I'll do test="#{id ne null}" in the when clause.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I used to have same exception using attributes in Mojarra 2.0.3 :S I am not a hundred percent sure but it seems like some *reserved words stuff* or similar :S

As a workaround you may try to use `id_` attribute name instead of `id` directly;

---

Good luck